# IntelliJ Navigation Bar Hot Key

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-15

IntelliJ 15 says that the hot key is ⌥↖︎ to open the Navigation Bar, but how do you do this?

I assumed that it was <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> but that doesn't seem to do anything in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Oh just playing around with it a little more, I had to include the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

So it's <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> if anyone else was trying to figure this out.